# ngMaterial dependency not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

There are 2 pages home.html and about.html I am using 'ui.router' when I click router (about.html) then current view (home.html) down  and new view appears on top and vice versa. This is happening only when ngMaterial include as a dependency
and I want to use angular material .
any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just updated bower and it resolved it. So, solution was:

```
bower update
```